# Pause auto-rotate on mouseover (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I'm using a content slider plugin that is nice but lacks one important feature: does *not* stop auto-rotating slides on mouseover.

Here's the relevant part from the script:

```
var dotimer = function (x){
    if((opts.auto) == true) {
        if(timer != null) 
            clearInterval(timer);

        timer = setInterval(function() {
                $(opts.next).click();
                }, 3000);
    }
}

dotimer();
```

Full script can be previewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/juuQc/)

I want the rotation to pause on mouseover and resume on mouseout.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here: http://www.dlocc.com/articles/jflow-slider-auto-slider-with-pause-functionality/

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set and clear the timer in the `hover` event:

```
var stopTimer() = function () {
    if (!timer) return;
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = false;
};
$(something).hover(
    function() { stopTimer(); },
    function() { doTimer();   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(opts.slides).hover(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
},
function() {
  dotimer();
});
```